# Помогите оптимизировать рабочий код python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан двумерный массив и два числа: i и j. Поменяйте в массиве столбцы с номерами i и j.

Входные данные

Программа получает на вход в первой строке размеры массива n≤100 и m≤100, затем элементы массива, а в последней строке числа i и j.

Выходные данные

Выведите полученный массив.

Не пойму, как сделать, чтобы s не уползало за рамки, так как если я понижу перебор до n-2, нарушается сам код

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
i,j=map(int,input().split())
for s in range(0,n):
    m=a[(i-1)+s][j-1]
    a[(i-1)+s][j-1]=a[(i-1)+s][j]
    a[(i-1)+s][j]=m
for row in a:
    for elem in row:
        print(elem,end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 5):

Что-то у вас странное написано... Поменять элементы местами в общем случае записывается так: `a, b = b, a`.
В вашем случае делается простой проход по рядам и производится обмен содержимым между i-ым и j-ым элементами каждого ряда.

```
for row in range(n):
    a[row][i], a[row][j] = a[row][j], a[row][i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет такое решение, конкретно к вашему коду не имеющее отношение. Воспользуюсь модулем `numpy`. Сделаем матрицу `5x5`, для примера

```py
import numpy as np
matrix2d = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
print(matrix2d)

"""вывод
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
"""
```

Функция для замены столбцов может выглядеть вот так

```py
def change_col(matrix, i, j):
  matrix[:,[i, j]] = matrix[:,[j, i]]
```

Поменяем 2ой и 3ий

```py
change_col(matrix2d, 2, 3)
print(matrix2d)

"""вывод
[[ 0  1  3  2  4]
 [ 5  6  8  7  9]
 [10 11 13 12 14]
 [15 16 18 17 19]
 [20 21 23 22 24]]
"""
```